# Error in access different views

Tags: vtk, dicom, itk

I want to create Axial, Sagittal and Coronal views from a volume. At first I say that my volume is achieved from a series of DICOM images using DicomSeriesReadImageWrite2.cxx from itk library. The output is a .mha file.

Now I want to create different views using this data. So I used image ImageSlicing.cxx example. But the out put is a black window.
What shoud I do?

This is the code:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkImageReader2.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkImageActor.h>
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkImageReader2.h"
#include "vtkMatrix4x4.h"
#include "vtkImageReslice.h"
#include "vtkLookupTable.h"
#include "vtkImageMapToColors.h"
#include "vtkImageActor.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"
#include "vtkInteractorStyleImage.h"
#include "vtkCommand.h"
#include "vtkImageData.h"
#include "vtkImageMapper3D.h"
#include "vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline.h"
#include "vtkInformation.h"
#include "vtkAutoInit.h"


VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2); // VTK was built with vtkRenderingOpenGL2
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);

// The mouse motion callback, to turn "Slicing" on and off
class vtkImageInteractionCallback : public vtkCommand
{
public:

    static vtkImageInteractionCallback *New() {
        return new vtkImageInteractionCallback;
    };

    vtkImageInteractionCallback() {
        this->Slicing = 0;
        this->ImageReslice = nullptr;
        this->Interactor = nullptr;
    };

    void SetImageReslice(vtkImageReslice *reslice) {
        this->ImageReslice = reslice;
    };

    vtkImageReslice *GetImageReslice() {
        return this->ImageReslice;
    };

    void SetInteractor(vtkRenderWindowInteractor *interactor) {
        this->Interactor = interactor;
    };

    vtkRenderWindowInteractor *GetInteractor() {
        return this->Interactor;
    };

    void Execute(vtkObject *, unsigned long event, void *) override
    {
        vtkRenderWindowInteractor *interactor = this->GetInteractor();

        int lastPos[2];
        interactor->GetLastEventPosition(lastPos);
        int currPos[2];
        interactor->GetEventPosition(currPos);

        if (event == vtkCommand::LeftButtonPressEvent)
        {
            this->Slicing = 1;
        }
        else if (event == vtkCommand::LeftButtonReleaseEvent)
        {
            this->Slicing = 0;
        }
        else if (event == vtkCommand::MouseMoveEvent)
        {
            if (this->Slicing)
            {
                vtkImageReslice *reslice = this->ImageReslice;

                // Increment slice position by deltaY of mouse
                int deltaY = lastPos[1] - currPos[1];

                reslice->Update();
                double sliceSpacing = reslice->GetOutput()->GetSpacing()[2];
                vtkMatrix4x4 *matrix = reslice->GetResliceAxes();
                // move the center point that we are slicing through
                double point[4];
                double center[4];
                point[0] = 0.0;
                point[1] = 0.0;
                point[2] = sliceSpacing * deltaY;
                point[3] = 1.0;
                matrix->MultiplyPoint(point, center);
                matrix->SetElement(0, 3, center[0]);
                matrix->SetElement(1, 3, center[1]);
                matrix->SetElement(2, 3, center[2]);
                interactor->Render();
            }
            else
            {
                vtkInteractorStyle *style = vtkInteractorStyle::SafeDownCast(
                    interactor->GetInteractorStyle());
                if (style)
                {
                    style->OnMouseMove();
                }
            }
        }
    };

private:

    // Actions (slicing only, for now)
    int Slicing;

    // Pointer to vtkImageReslice
    vtkImageReslice *ImageReslice;

    // Pointer to the interactor
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor *Interactor;
};

// The program entry point
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //if (argc < 2)
    //{
    //  cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " DATADIR/headsq/quarter" << endl;
    //  return 1;
    //}

    // Start by loading some data.
    std::string inputFilename = "out.mha";

    // Read file
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReader2> reader =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReader2>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
    reader->SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();
    reader->Update();

    // Calculate the center of the volume
    int extent[6];
    double spacing[3];
    double origin[3];


    reader->GetOutputInformation(0)->Get(vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline::WHOLE_EXTENT(), extent);
    reader->GetOutput()->GetSpacing(spacing);
    reader->GetOutput()->GetOrigin(origin);

    double center[3];
    center[0] = origin[0] + spacing[0] * 0.5 * (extent[0] + extent[1]);
    center[1] = origin[1] + spacing[1] * 0.5 * (extent[2] + extent[3]);
    center[2] = origin[2] + spacing[2] * 0.5 * (extent[4] + extent[5]);

    // Matrices for axial, coronal, sagittal, oblique view orientations
    //static double axialElements[16] = {
    //         1, 0, 0, 0,
    //         0, 1, 0, 0,
    //         0, 0, 1, 0,
    //         0, 0, 0, 1 };

    //static double coronalElements[16] = {
    //         1, 0, 0, 0,
    //         0, 0, 1, 0,
    //         0,-1, 0, 0,
    //         0, 0, 0, 1 };

    static double sagittalElements[16] = {
        0, 0,-1, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        0,-1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1 };

    //static double obliqueElements[16] = {
    //         1, 0, 0, 0,
    //         0, 0.866025, -0.5, 0,
    //         0, 0.5, 0.866025, 0,
    //         0, 0, 0, 1 };

    // Set the slice orientation
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> resliceAxes =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
    resliceAxes->DeepCopy(sagittalElements);
    // Set the point through which to slice
    resliceAxes->SetElement(0, 3, center[0]);
    resliceAxes->SetElement(1, 3, center[1]);
    resliceAxes->SetElement(2, 3, center[2]);

    // Extract a slice in the desired orientation
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice> reslice =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageReslice>::New();
    reslice->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    reslice->SetOutputDimensionality(2);
    reslice->SetResliceAxes(resliceAxes);
    reslice->SetInterpolationModeToLinear();

    // Create a greyscale lookup table
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> table =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
    table->SetRange(0, 2000); // image intensity range
    table->SetValueRange(0.0, 1.0); // from black to white
    table->SetSaturationRange(0.0, 0.0); // no color saturation
    table->SetRampToLinear();
    table->Build();

    // Map the image through the lookup table
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors> color =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors>::New();
    color->SetLookupTable(table);
    color->SetInputConnection(reslice->GetOutputPort());

    // Display the image
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> actor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
    actor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(color->GetOutputPort());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> window =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    window->AddRenderer(renderer);

    // Set up the interaction
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage> imageStyle =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleImage>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    interactor->SetInteractorStyle(imageStyle);
    window->SetInteractor(interactor);
    window->Render();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageInteractionCallback> callback =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageInteractionCallback>::New();
    callback->SetImageReslice(reslice);
    callback->SetInteractor(interactor);

    imageStyle->AddObserver(vtkCommand::MouseMoveEvent, callback);
    imageStyle->AddObserver(vtkCommand::LeftButtonPressEvent, callback);
    imageStyle->AddObserver(vtkCommand::LeftButtonReleaseEvent, callback);

    // Start interaction
    // The Start() method doesn't return until the window is closed by the user
    interactor->Start();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to render a simpler, already working example as this one : https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Triangle

Comment: Yes I just try it and it works fine after I add; 


 #include "vtkAutoInit.h" 
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2); // VTK was built with vtkRenderingOpenGL2
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);

Comment: You may want to try and expand from your working example then.

Comment: I did not get your comment, are you say that this example has some informations that could help me? Which part?

Comment: There is something wrong in the code pasted here since you can't render anything. The VTK example is working. Try to converge.

Comment: Why you say there is something wrong and I can not render anything? Because of black output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in reading data. I used  pointer to read my data and problem solved.